# There are multiple column in my table and I want to skip one column if value is null for that one particular column in oracle update query?

Tags: sql, oracle

There are multiple column in my table and I want to skip one column if value is null for that one particular column and all other columns should be updated with there respective value in oracle update query.
Is there any simple way to do this ?

Example:
Let me explain my problem with  example:
I am using merge query like below :
merge into table_X  on (condition )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET  COLUMN_1=VALUE1 , COLUMN_2=VALUE_2,........
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (  COLUMN_1,COLUMN_2...) VALUES (VALUE_1,VALUE_2);

Now in update statement I want to skip the update for one column suppose COLUMN_2  if its value is null , but all other column should be updated . Basically I want to preserve the existing value when null is coming .

Comment: Yes; skip that column when you're writing that UPDATE statement.

Comment: What does "value is null for that one particular column" mean? Show the update statement that you have and explain the issue with it.

Comment: added the example .Please check once.

Comment: Use the function [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/NVL.html) in the assignment.

`COLUMN_2 = NVL(VALUE_2, COLUMN_2)`